# Razor Pages: Confused about all the return types and when to use them

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I'm generally confused about the "why" (not the "how") of using certain C# return types in Razor Pages. In some instances, I understand the "why", but am not clear on when I should use one over the other. My initial confusion began with the Asynchronous types, but I understand that now. It was also compounded by the `void` type, which I have a little better grasp of, but am still not fully comprehending.

I am studying several different snippets of code to get a better grasp, and could use some helpful explanations - the Docs and other sources are not really bringing it home for me.

Some of the methods come from some DI's, and aren't necessarily relevant (I think, for all I know it's the reason for using one return type over another, in which case I appreciate an explanation). Here are some various snippets that I am hoping the community can help me come to understand better as to the "why" using one return type over the other (or whether I should just stick with one type as it won't affect the result of what is being done).

First:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    ServicesContainer = _helper
        .GetRecentContentItemsByContentTypeAsync("Services")
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult()
        .SingleOrDefault();
    ServicesList = _helper
        .GetRecentContentItemsByContentTypeAsync("Service")
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult()
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedUtc)
        .Take(3);
}
```

The code itself I have no problem understanding - it's retrieving a container and list items inside. My Razor Page is just displaying the list items using a repeating `foreach` loop. I also understand the code is getting this information and it's the most basic example. So for no problem in my understanding.

Second:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string projectTitle)
{
    Project = _helper
        .QueryContentItemsAsync(q => q
            .Where(c => c.DisplayText == projectTitle))
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult()
        .SingleOrDefault();

    var relatedProjects = 
        (IEnumerable<string>)Project?
            .Content
            .Project.RelatedProjects?
            .ContentItemIds?.ToObject<string[]>();

    if (relatedProjects?.Count() > 0)
    {
        RelatedProjects = await
            _helper.GetContentItemsByIdAsync(relatedProjects);
    }
}
```

The above is also retrieving a "container" that may have items (RelatedProjects), but in this case it's doing it a bit differently since there may not be anything to list other than the Project itself. But why is it using `Task` instead of just `OnGet`?

Third:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    HeaderInfo = await _helper
        .GetContentItemByAliasAsync("alias:fullwidth");

    return Page();
}
```

Here it's just a single item. But again, why use `Task` and why do an `<IActionResult>` to return the page when all the other code doesn't require returning a page? And why isn't it using `OnGetAsync`?

There is nothing special about any of the items - they are all stored on a CMS (nothing dynamic about them, for example). The first, a container with list items. The second an item with potentially related items (if they exist in the CMS, which they don't). The third is just a single item.

And why use `void` on the first but not

Thanks in advance for sharing any insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever a request is made to `OnGet()`, IIS must wait for the data to be returned before it can handle other requests. By making `OnGet()` asynchronous, this allows IIS to perform other tasks while it waits for your data to get returned. This reduces bottlenecks and it makes IIS perform faster and more efficient.

Whenever a method is marked as `async`, it must return a `Task` object. If your method has nothing to return, then it still must be marked as `Task OnGetAsync()`. If your method does return a value, you can specify the return type in the `Task` object, as in `Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()`.

So for your methods, here's what's happening:

```
public void OnGet()
{
     // Synchronous method that returns nothing
     // IIS stops handling requests here until your method returns
}

public async Task OnGetAsync(string projectTitle)
{
    // Asynchronous method that returns nothing.
    // When your code reaches the await keyword,
    // IIS resumes handling other tasks while awaiting
    // for your method to return
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    // Asynchronous method that returns an IActionResult value
    // When your code reaches the await keyword,
    // IIS resumes handling other tasks while awaiting
    // for your method to return
}
```

Comment: Clear and concise. Thanks. Follow-up: it isn't clear to me if I can just go ahead and make all my code return `IActionResult`, since it seems that both sets of code just get information from the CMS while I display the information on the Razor Page. Does it matter? In other words, is there anything special about either the first or third snippets that makes it a requirement to do each the way they are done?

Comment: @REMESQ You should only return an IActionResult or a Task<IActionResult> if you need to return some kind of ActionResult. Ideally, you should be specific about the type you want to return. You don't usually need to return an IActionResult if you want  to show the page connected to the PageModel where these methods are located. You will need to return an IActionResult if you want to redirect,return some JSON, a NotFoundResult etc: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results

Comment: @MikeBrind _"Should only"_ is generally based upon a reason. Would that reason in this case be performance?, or it is only a matter of order?, or...?

Comment: @LGSon _Should only_ as in illustrating your intentions. `return Page()` is implicit in a page handler.

Comment: @MikeBrind Thanks ... hoped that were the reason :)

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
> {
>     HeaderInfo = await _helper
>         .GetContentItemByAliasAsync("alias:fullwidth");
>
>     return Page();
> }
> ```

You don't actually need to return anything from this method. You could just as easily have written

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    HeaderInfo = await _helper
        .GetContentItemByAliasAsync("alias:fullwidth");
}
```

When you call the `Page()` method, the current page is displayed. This happens implicitly in any event if no other return type is specified.

Typically, you would only call the `Page()` method as one of a number of possible return types, where the other return types are IActionResults. The most common example is when a form is posted:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("Success"); // redirect as part of PRG
    }
    else
    {
        return Page(); // redisplay the page with validation errors
    }
}
```

In this case you must declare a return type (instead of void or Task) because you want to use the RedirectToPage method, which returns a RedirectToResult (a type of IActionResult). You must also provide a suitable return type in the `else` case, hence the call to `return Page()`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Useful since I have plans to both return some JSON in other pages as well as have a few form pages as well. Again, thanks.

Comment: @remesq you can also use Web API to return JSON https://www.learnrazorpages.com/web-api